# How to solve "unrecognized command line option '-std=gnu11'" error?

Tags: c, gcc

I am planning to run a TCP client using C with Eclipse and here is the code. I added the output as well. Any ideas why I get the following output?

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>      /* for printf(), fprintf() */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for exit() */

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   int sockfd,n;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
   char sendline[1000];
   char recvline[1000];

   if (argc != 2)
   {
      printf("usage:  client <IP address>\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

   bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
   servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);

   connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

   while (fgets(sendline, 10000,stdin) != NULL)
   {
      sendto(sockfd,sendline,strlen(sendline),0,
             (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
      n=recvfrom(sockfd,recvline,10000,0,NULL,NULL);
      recvline[n]=0;
      fputs(recvline,stdout);
   }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

and here the output:

```
*****11:25:59 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project tcpcli ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu11 -o tcpclient.o "..\\tcpclient.c" 
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=gnu11'*****
```

Comment: Looks like something in your the build options in your project configuration... probably you are setting a compiler version that your installation does not support.

Comment: thanks for your comment. If I do not use "-std=gnu11", I will get so many errors such as below: undefined reference to `__imp_socket' undefined reference to `__imp_inet_addr' undefined reference to `__imp_htons' undefined reference to `__imp_connect' undefined reference to `__imp_sendto'

Comment: Your IDE or build system seems to call your compiler with the option `-std=gnu11`, which your compiler does not support (probably because it is very outdated, or MSVC). I'm not using an IDE myself, but I recommend clicking around in the GUI and selecting an older C standard like `C99`.

Comment: I just installed "gcc-4.6.4-64.exe" and latest version of CDT. I even tried -std=c99, I got more errors.

Comment: gcc 4.7 seems to know about -std=gnu11, no luck with 4.6

Comment: I installed the gnu 4.8.1 but got different error as below: undefined reference to `socket@12' ,  undefined reference to `bzero'
undefined reference to `inet_addr@4'
undefined reference to `htons@4'
undefined reference to `connect@12'
undefined reference to `sendto@24'

Comment: Upgrade to a version of GCC that understands the option.  Or change to `-std=gnu99`.  They're your basic options.

Comment: These new ones are other errors, that were previously shadowed by the faulty flag. Handle them separately, google or post new questions

Comment: Tell us what toolchain you're using (version, host and target). `gcc -v` will give all this info. It looks like your build scripts/makefile are missing a library that needs to be specified (`libwsock32.a`?).

Comment: If your compiler doesn't support `-std=gnu11`, it *might* support `-std=gnu1x`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I could finally manage to compile and run my codes in windows environment.

gcc -v => gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)
I used -std=gnu1x in C/C++ Build, Settings, Miscellaneous
and in MinGW C Linker -> Libraries, I used wsock32

Answer (score 2):

I could finally manage to compile and run my codes in windows environment.

```
gcc -v => gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)
```

I used `-std=gnu1x` in C/C++ Build, Settings, Miscellaneous and in MinGW C Linker -> Libraries, I used `wsock32` –  mazkopolo